# letter document class and babel/magyar not compatible any more?

Tags: texlive, babel, letters

I am recently having trouble with combining the `letter` document class with the `magyar` language option of the `babel` package. The weird thing is that the last time when I had to use this combination (about half a year ago) there was no problem with it. To give an example, even the following code wouldn't compile on my machine at the moment:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone of you have had this problem? I am using TeX Live 2012 on Mac OS X 10.6. I updated all of my packages with the TeX Live Manager, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Any ideas?

Thank you indeed for the help,
Ádám

EDIT:
This is what I get when I run LaTeX on the above code (edited again to get the file list):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Lorem Ipsum.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 piedmontese, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian
, serbianc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, u
ppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls
Document Class: letter 1999/04/29 v1.2z Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/magyar.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
No file "Lorem Ipsum".aux.

LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage{t1enc} with
               \usepackage[magyar]{babel}, to get accented chars hyphenated.


LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} with
               \usepackage[magyar]{babel}.

(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.181 \@onlypreamble
                    \makelabels
? 

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.181 \@onlypreamble\makelabels

? 
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./Lorem Ipsum.aux)

 *File List*
  letter.cls    1999/04/29 v1.2z Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
  magyar.ldf    2007/10/19 v1.5 Magyar support from the babel v3.7 system
 ***********

 )</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on "Lorem Ipsum.pdf" (1 page, 12274 bytes).
SyncTeX written on "Lorem Ipsum.synctex.gz"
Transcript written on "Lorem Ipsum.log".
```

Comment: With my updated-today TeX Live set up, I get `magyar.ldf    2005/03/30 v1.4j` (other file versions identical). Did you install something by hand? (There are a number of versions of `magyar.ldf` in circulation, and one of the big challenges for `babel` is sorting this.)

Comment: something very odd about that log file `(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls` appears twice so the class file has been loaded twice, which accounts for most of the errors.

Comment: @JosephWright apparently, this must be a hand-installed version of `magyar.ldf`, although I don't recall installing that by hand, and I also updated TeX Live today. In fact, I read everywhere that it is strongly recommended to use the 1.5 version of `magyar.ldf`, since many sources state that the 1.4 version has serious problems regarding Hungarian typesetting rules which has been corrected in the 1.5 version. Apparently, there might be a bug with its interaction with `letter`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing this out. Do you have any idea how to overcome this? I didn't actually know that I'm loading it twice and I don't really know how to avoid it.

Comment: I don't see how you can get that log from that input (your file runs without error for me). I see you have a space in the filename which is living dangerously but I just tried saving your MWE in such a file and it still worked for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, version 1.5 is used. This style is maintained directly by Péter Szabó. Try

```
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=safest}
```

before loading `babel` and then read the docs available on http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/ . One of them explains: "if a document doesn't compile, but it compiles with `defaults=safest`, individual options can be turned on one-by-one to see which of them causes the compatibility problem."

Comment: The so-called 1.5 version purposely loads again the class, to do something related to page style. This, in my opinion, is a *VERY BAD THING*.

Comment: @egreg The Hungarian tipography is very different from english or italian one. So the magyar.ldf has to redefine the page style of the standard classes. This is NOT VERY BAD THING, but VERY NECESSARY.

Comment: @tomacs This is what the solution I posted says. I copied verbatim from the English docs, and it's a general solution for most problem with `magyar` - if it works with `defaults=safest`, then read to documentation and see which option causes the problem.

Comment: @tomacs I understand it, but the file is a collection of undocumented hacks.

Comment: magyar.ldf documentation: www.math.bme.hu/latex/magyarldf-doc.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Use the newest `magyar.ldf` and this will work!!!

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{defaults=hu-min}{magyar.ldf}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```