# Conflict between babel magyar and scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: babel, scrlayer-scrpage

My `[magyar]{babel}` and `scrlayer-scrpage` packages seem not to be working together… This is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}

\section{Test document}

This is a test document.

\end{document}
```

The error I get here is:

> E: .../Tester.tex:6 Illegal parameter number in definition of
>   \reserved@b \begin{document}

Can someone help me figuring out what it means?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! I know that `magyar` can cause problems. The solution described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100358) seems to work also in your case.

Comment: @campa might actually be a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

It seems that

```
\makeatletter
\def\@@magyar@setup@psheadings{}
\makeatother
```

after loading `babel` solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[markcase=noupper,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\makeatletter
\def\@@magyar@setup@psheadings{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test document}
This is a test document.
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used option `automark` for `scrlayer-scrpage` to get the section title in header.

Result:

[image]